# Flutter widget is not showing its showing in hot reload

Tags: flutter

I am showing widget by loop issue is its not showing a widget when i use HotReload then its showing the list widget

```
class _CartPageState extends State<CartPage> {
  void navigateToAddressPage() {
    Get.to(AddressPage());
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    this._query();
  }

  List<Widget> textWidgetList = List<Widget>();

  void _query() async {
    print('cart');
    final dbHelper = DatabaseHelper.instance;

    final allRows = await dbHelper.queryAllRows();
    print(allRows);
    print('query all rows:');
    allRows.forEach((row) => print(row));

    for (int i = 0; i < allRows.length; i++) {
      textWidgetList.add(Card(
        elevation: 5.0,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
        ),
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
        child: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 120.0,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                  // child: CachedNetworkImage(
                  //   imageUrl:
                  //   'https://i.pinimg.com/564x/7f/0f/dc/7f0fdc10a9cb26e78d8e6257e1b06fb6.jpg',
                  //   height: 100.0,
                  //   width: 100.0,
                  // ),
                  child: Image.asset(
                    allRows[i]['image'],
                    height: 100,
                    width: 100,
                  )),
              SizedBox(width: 12.0),
              Expanded(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            child: Text(
                              allRows[i]['title'],
                              textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                              maxLines: 3,
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(width: 5.0),
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () {},
                                child: Icon(
                                  FlutterIcons.delete_outline_mco,
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            child: Text(
                              allRows[i]['price'],
                            ),
                          ),
                          // Counter(),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ));
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: buildAppBar(context),
      body: Container(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(height: 12.0),
              Column(children: textWidgetList),

            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can see in code i am showing data in for loop and then show widget but dont know why its not showing a widget its showing when i use hot reload. I am fetching data from sqllite so i think its not the issue screen load first and then data is loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you miss a `setState((){});` in the end of your `_query()` method. What happens is that `_query()` is invoked as soon as the widget is created and then populates the `textWidgetList`, but you never actually tell Flutter that it needs to refresh the UI.

When you press hot-reload, it actually does that, rebuilds all widgets (or its states) so you can actually see the `textWidgetList` changes.

To solve your issue, just don't forget to call `setState((){})` at the end of your `_query()` method, for example.